# Problem accessing values in dictionaries that are lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to determine for a big amount of values whether they appear in lists that are values of dictionaries. To make it more clear:

(this dictionary is converted from a df using 'series' as argument)

```py
my_dict = {
    'one': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'two': ['1', '2', '3'],
    'three': ['1', '3', '3']
}
```

Using the following loop to check existence:

```py
for id in frame[column]: 
    # this are the values of which existence needs to be checked
    for key in dict.keys():
        frame[key] = id in my_dict[key]
```

This should create a matrix that shows for every dict key as column name, whether the id appears in it. Problem is I'm getting all false negatives. I also checked with a single statement:

```
'2' in my_dict['one']
```

This is returning False. I've been trying to figure it out for hours. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

Comment: your input dictionary is a syntax error: no quotes, no commas. Please fix this

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you avoid naming your variable 'dict' since that is the name of the built-in dictionary constructor ```dict()```.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, made the changes.

Answer (score -3):

```
my_dict={
 'one':[1,2,3],
 'two':[1,2,3]
}
for i in my_dict:

print max(my_dict[i])
```

Comment: You did not explain what exactly was wrong with the OP's code or what you did to fix it.